# How do I change the working directory for an Eclipse run configuration?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a single Eclipse run configuration for which I want to set the working directory.  How do I do this?

I glanced through the different tabs for a run configuration, including the Environment tab, but didn't see anything obvious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Yep]

This is on Kepler SR1. Arguments tab.

Comment: Wow, I'm blind.  Don't know how I missed it with the red box around it.  :P  Nice project name!

Answer (score 3):

In a Java Application run config on the tab "Arguments" on the bottom where it says "Working directory".

Comment: Wow, I'm blind.  Thanks.